# Can I select classes by order like this?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

So I have this HTML here generated by Wordpress. I want to select the DIVs seperately using JS. Is this possible? Can I maybe select them by the order on which JS finds them in my HTML?

I tried if something like this would be possible (By adding an index number) but I believe that is used only for the LI element. But you get the idea. The end result is to add a different classname to each div object using .className

```js
var koffie = document.getElementsByClassName("g-gridstatistic-item-text2")[0];
var brain = document.getElementsByClassName("g-gridstatistic-item-text2")[1];
var tevred = document.getElementsByClassName("g-gridstatistic-item-text2")[2];

console.log(koffie);
console.log(brain);
console.log(tevred);
```

```html
<div class="g-gridstatistic-wrapper g-gridstatistic-3cols">
    <div class="g-gridstatistic-item">
    <div class="g-gridstatistic-item-wrapper">
    <div class="g-gridstatistic-item-text1 odometer" data-odometer-value="4"></div>
    <div class="g-gridstatistic-item-text2">Kopjes koffie per dag</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="g-gridstatistic-item">
    <div class="g-gridstatistic-item-wrapper">
    <div class="g-gridstatistic-item-text1 odometer" data-odometer-value="14"></div>
    <div class="g-gridstatistic-item-text2">Brainstormsessies per week</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="g-gridstatistic-item">
    <div class="g-gridstatistic-item-wrapper">
    <div class="g-gridstatistic-item-text1 odometer" data-odometer-value="12"></div>
    <div class="g-gridstatistic-item-text2">Tevreden klanten</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You selected all the elements you wanted, am I wrong? What are you trying to do?

Comment: You are correct, but I want to select them seperately.

Comment: Be more precise please

Comment: When using document.getElementsByClassName() I can select HTML DOM Objects by their classname. However I have duplicate classnames in my HTML file. I want to be able to select them on the className and the order on which they appear on my page, seperately.

Next I want to edit their className value seperate. They all need an added class which differentiates per div. So I have to select them seperate on their classname while they all have the same classname.

Comment: Can you update your question and also include, what you want the end-result to look like? Maybe a loop can solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry but this forum editor is really not letting me edit it due to spacing or something. Ive been trying to edit it for 15 minutes now. cant make it work.

I want the end result to look like the DIVs to have added classes after the classes which are already in there. These classes are all different per div, which is why I have to select them seperately.

Comment: The thing is what classes do you want to add. A generated class will probably have no css backing it up and thus serve no purpose. Though to do that look up on foreach-loops.

Comment: Oh, I'm trying to add classes for FontAwesome icons. My theme runs on Rockettheme's Gantry framework and offers CSS support for the full icon library. For example, I want the first DIV to have 'fa', 'fa-coffee' and  'fa-rw'.

Comment: Create an array with the classes you want to add. use a for-loop to assign class 0 to div 0, class 1 to div 1 and so on. Read up on arrays and for-loops that should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript code is looking for DOM elements before it checks whether the DOM has even loaded. Try wrapping it in an event listener, like so:

**JS**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

var koffie = document.getElementsByClassName("g-gridstatistic-item-text2")[0];
var brain = document.getElementsByClassName("g-gridstatistic-item-text2")[1];
var tevred = document.getElementsByClassName("g-gridstatistic-item-text2")[2];

//console.log(koffie);
//console.log(brain);
//console.log(tevred);

/*  to evidence that targeting works:  */
brain.classList.add('addedClass'); 

});
```

**CSS**

```
.addedClass {
  font-size:22px;
  color:red;
}
```

Full demo here:
https://jsbin.com/saxizeyabo/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

simply like this

```
var yourVariableName = document.getElementsByClassName("g-gridstatistic-item-text2");

console.log(youVariableName[0]);
console.log(youVariableName[1]);
```

and so on like an array

Comment: No, this did not work for me. I am trying to place them in seperate variables so I can add information to the object className. Running this simply gives me undefined in my console.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.g-gridstatistic-item-text2').item(0);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

This way, you can just use CSS-Selectors

Comment: Based on your suggestion I came up with this

var koffie = document.querySelectorAll('.g-gridstatistic-item-text2');

koffie[0].className += "fa fa-coffee fa-rw";
koffie[1].className += "fa fa-flash fa-rw";
koffie[2].className += "fa fa-handshake-o fa-rw";

It gives me the error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'koffie[0].className')

Comment: Yes, because its not an array, its an object, and u use the method item to get it as shown...

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work.

```
var classes = document.getElementsByClassName('g-gridstatistic-item-text2');
for(var i=0; i<=classes.length; i++) {
    var appendClass = 'your_class_name'+i;
    classes[i].classList.add(appendClass);
}
```